# Loading a link multiple times (at different times)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an exercise in which I need to make a page for my school, in this exercise I am tasked with making a page in which the user will be able to see faces from everyone in the class. I wanted to think "a little outside the box" and use https://thispersondoesnotexist.com to generated different faces.

I found https://fakeface.rest that allows me to give directions to thispersondoesnotexist.com allowing me to set an age range and a size for the image https://fakeface.rest/thumb/view?minimum_age=16&maximum_age=25

Here is my issue however: The page is loading every links at the same time and displaying the same image multiple times like this: [image: Screenshot with the two same pictures]

That's why I wanted to know if there was a way for me to load the two images at a different time so that they show a different "person" each time.

It would be preferable to avoid using js (html and CSS) but if this is the only solution then so be it: I'll use it

Ps: I tried using eager/lazy loading but that didn't work

Comment: Please include the code you're using to load the images.

Comment: "If you want to insert multiple different faces and prevent the browser caching then you can append any number or random string to the end of the endpoint as follows:" https://fakeface.rest/face/view/1?gender=male or https://fakeface.rest/face/view/anythingcangohere_theapidoesntdoanythingwithit?gender=male, so you could just add a number after each one (1 through the max size of the class) to generate a separate image for each "member"

Answer (score 1):

Here I added an additional garbage parameter to each url, to make the urls different:

```html
<img src="https://fakeface.rest/thumb/view?minimum_age=16&maximum_age=25&blart1">
<img src="https://fakeface.rest/thumb/view?minimum_age=16&maximum_age=25&blart2">
<img src="https://fakeface.rest/thumb/view?minimum_age=16&maximum_age=25&blart3">
<img src="https://fakeface.rest/thumb/view?minimum_age=16&maximum_age=25&blart4">
```

Comment: Blart Lol! Made me laugh

Answer (score 0):

They actually tell you how to do that with the API:

> If you want to insert multiple different faces and prevent the browser caching then you can append any number or random string to the end of the endpoint as follows:
> https://fakeface.rest/face/view/1?gender=male
> https://fakeface.rest/face/view/anythingcangohere_theapidoesntdoanythingwithit?gender=male

Source: [inserting into html](https://hankhank10.github.io/fakeface/index.html#inserting-into-html) (scroll past the image)